# Doubts on using oauth tokens for Gmail APIs

Tags: gmail-api

I am accessing Gmail IMAP and SMTP servers using oauth 2.0 token with just this one scope **'https://mail.google.com/'**. Is this scope enough to access all the Gmail APIs?

Thanks,
Anurag

Answer (score 2):

Authorization scopes are permissions you request users to authorize for your app. When https://mail.google.com/ scope is used, it gives full access to the account(users), including permanent deletion of threads and messages. Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes) for documentation on the gmail scopes.